# How can I solve libstdc++ portability problem

Tags: c++, g++, dynamic-linking

I have built a binary that runs in my system(fedora 30), but when I want to run that on ubuntu I get below error:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./App)
```

what is the standard way to solve this problem? or do I always need to rebuild my app on various os to run it?

Comment: This is not glibc's version tag but GNU (GCC) libstdc++'s.

Comment: Unless you are using API's that are specific to your Fedora OS, or your Ubuntu environment is a different architecture than your Fedora environment, you would normally provide an installer or at least ship all of your programs dependencies with your code.  If the architectures don't match, you would need to cross-compile or recompile it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the standard way to solve this problem?

The standard way to solve this is to define your *minimum* requirements, and then build your binary in such a way that it only requires this minimum, and nothing else.

For example, if you build your program on a RedHat 7.2 distribution, and don't use C++, your program will run on *all* Linux distributions that are not older than 20 years.

> or do I always need to rebuild my app on various os to run it?

You don't.

In the particular case of `GLIBCXX_3.4.26` version symbol, you have built your binary with GCC 9.0.0 (or later): see the [ABI document](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html).

The binary will not run on any system with only GCC-8.x runtime installed.

One way to avoid this requirement is to link with `-static-libstdc++` flag. Your binary will be larger (possibly *much* larger), and it may require to be distributed in a different form (due to the viral nature of GPL; check with your lawyer), but it will work on older distributions.

Alternatively, if you build your binary "regularly" on a GCC-8.x based distribution, the binary should work just fine on a GCC-9.x based newer one.

Another solution for this is to distribute your binary in a docker container that has all the prerequisites.

P.S. I don't suggest that you actually run a physical RedHat-7.2 host. Using an isolated VM with an old distribution just for building should work.

Comment: @employed_russain thanks for your detailed response, just because I am a beginner, "and don't use C++, your program will run on all Linux distributions" means that if I write my app with c and I did not use c++ I won't have(or at least I have less) portability problems?

Comment: @alirezasadeghpour Correct: pure-C programs are easier to make portable than C++ (but C++ is not too bad either). When you add X11 and/or Qt and/or GL into the mix, keeping the binary portable becomes much harder.

Comment: I second using a RedHat/Centos 7 distribution.  The devtoolset compilers link against a very old version of libstdc++, and statically link in new C++ features as needed.  https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/.  This can be run in a docker image,  If you are interested in Python, the manylinux2014 is a good redhat 7 based image.